# JSON files aren't shown in Open File Dialog while in the filter

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I've created an OpenFileDialog in C# and set its filter to this snippet:

`OpenFileDialog openDailog = _MainForm.openFileDialog1;
 openDailog.Filter = "Json files (*.json) | *.json |Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";`

The problem is that it doesn't show JSON files but text files are shown in the windows. Is this filter wrong for JSON files or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have spaces in your `Filter`, and the filter is very sensitive to spaces. Now it matches on `[SPACE]*.json[SPACE]`, not `*.json`.

Remove the spaces and you'll be fine:

```
openDailog.Filter = "Json files (*.json)|*.json|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not have spaces in your filter expression. Remove them from the expression. It should work then.

```
openDailog.Filter = "Json files (*.json)|*.json|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Thanks

Comment: You are simply repeating an answer that has been given 4 minutes before.